# Exclude a dir when using pathlib glob

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

lets say I have a dir named `root`

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path('./root')
print(sorted(root.glob('*')))
```

**Output:**

```py
[WindowsPath('G:/root/0'),
WindowsPath('G:/root/1'),
WindowsPath('G:/root/2'),
WindowsPath('G:/root/3')]
```

I want to **exclude** dir `WindowsPath('G:/root/0')` & get this output using `glob()`

```py
[WindowsPath('G:/root/1'),
WindowsPath('G:/root/2'),
WindowsPath('G:/root/3')]
```

I would also like to know how to **exclude** multiple such dirs using `glob()`
say this time I want to exclude `WindowsPath('G:/root/0')` & `WindowsPath('G:/root/3')`

If I cannot do this using `glob()`, other suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`Path.glob()` can not exclude paths (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)).

But you can filter the results afterwards, e.g. by using a list comprehension:

```
from pathlib import Path

root = Path('./root')
all_paths = sorted(root.glob('*'))
exclude_paths = [WindowsPath('G:/root/0'), WindowsPath('G:/root/3')]
filtered_paths = [path for path in all_paths if path not in exclude_paths]
```

Comment: Can we not make a pattern which excludes these path ??

Comment: You can use `exclude_paths = Path.glob(exclude_pattern)` to create all paths matching that pattern.

Comment: Or you could use a more specific pattern than `*`, that only matches those paths you want to include.

Comment: I am not that good with regex but searching online I found people using patterns which excluded or negated some substrings. Those patterns were quite complicated though!!

Comment: I agree, that's what I am looking for! a good pattern.

Comment: actually my dir consists of 50-60 sub-dirs and I need to exclude only 2 to 3 of them. that's why I am searching for a pattern.

Comment: So your question is not about python or pathlib, but only about finding a fitting [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) pattern? Then be more specific in your question and add the necessary information, like which paths you want to match and which paths you want to exclude.

Comment: that's right!! I need a good pattern. and I have mentioned already all the paths in my root folder and the paths to exclude!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218683/discussion-between-niklas-mertsch-and-manan).